# Jquery Animate Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replicate the animation/hide attributes of this website, http://fivetailors.com/#!home ,when navigating through different pages. Each "page" is represented as its own div so this website is only one page. The current "page" and the "page" that the user is accessing are the only two divs that should be visible. When the user clicks on a new "page", it uses scroll to and animate to show that content.

In its current state all of the divs in between the current div and the div they are accessing are shown, but they should be hidden. Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".page").hide();
    $("#page0").show();

    var lastPage = "#page0";

    $('#nav ul li a').click(function(){

        var el = $(this).attr('href');
        var elWrapped = $(el);

        $(el).show();


        scrollToDiv(elWrapped,40);
        sleep(500);


        $(lastPage).hide();
        lastPage=el;
        return false;

    });

    function scrollToDiv(element,navheight){



        var offset = element.offset();
        var offsetTop = offset.top;
        var totalScroll = offsetTop-navheight;

        $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: totalScroll
        }, 500);

    }   
});

$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
    parallaxScroll();
});
```

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing an example on that site.

Comment: Sorry, website isn't correct. http://fivetailors.com/#!contact